# Is there any way to route an audio file into an iPhone mic input?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone

I have an iPhone-only app which only accepts microphone input.

I want to input a pre-recorded high-quality audio file into the app, but it only accepts input from the microphone.

On macOS, it would be possible to create a virtual microphone device, select that as the audio input, playback an audio file, and output it to the virtual microphone. However, that workflow is not possible on iOS.

Is there any way to achieve this on an iPhone?

One idea I had was to connect a professional-grade microphone supporting USB to the iPhone using a powered lightning-to-USB connector, and playing the audio track back at a high quality, but this seems like overkill for a simple task like this. Is there any better way to reroute this audio file to the app's microphone input?

Comment: His is unlikely to work.  Apps are sandboxed so one app interfacing to a microphone cannot have another app interact with it,

Comment: I see, do you think there could be a special type of microphone, which can output a pure audio file as though it's a microphone? Maybe that would work. Although I guess that type of question doesn't belong on Ask Different anymore

Comment: You’re looking for a [portable digital recorder](https://pro.sony/ue_US/products/portable-digital-recorders). It’s not the microphone that captures the audio; it just converts sound to electrical current.  The DAC is what converts analog electrical signals to digital to write to a file.